# Prevent line break after inline-block

Tags: html, css

In a page, I have a container of fixed width which contains an inline-block element, followed by some text.

Sometimes, this text will be wider than the container. When this happens, I want it to break to the next line (as seen in the first example below).

Sometimes, this text will also be too wide to display within the container. When this happens, I want the excess to be truncated (`overflow: hidden`). However, when I try doing this the obvious way, a line break gets inserted after the inline-block element (as seen in the second example).

I can work around this by wrapping the inline-block element and the first letter of the text together in a `<nobr>` element (as seen in the third example -- or an equivalent `white-space:nowrap` wrapper), but this seems like a really ugly way of going about things. Is there a better way of doing this?

```css
.container {
  outline: 2px solid blue;
  width: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px;
}

.inlineblock {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px; height: 1.5em; vertical-align: middle;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="inlineblock"></span>line breaks only at spaces
</div>

<div class="container">
  <span class="inlineblock"></span>widetextwidetextwidetext second line
</div>

<div class="container">
  <nobr><span class="inlineblock"></span>w</nobr>idetextwidetextwidetext ugly workaround
</div>
```

Comment: *" .. or an equivalent `white-space:nowrap` wrapper..."* - Why is that ugly? Seems like that's exactly what it is for. In fact, I overlooked that phrase and was about to provide an answer suggesting that approach. A `<nobr>` tag is the 1997 version of that same solution and [formally doesn't exist](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nobr), so I would opt for the CSS version.

Comment: Doesn't adding `white-space:nowrap;` to the `.container` do just what your looking for? Or am I missing something

Comment: @GolezTrol I consider that an "ugly" solution because it requires the first character of the text to be split from the rest -- consider what that would look like in a template, for instance. It's also impossible if the text needs to be wrapped in another element (e.g, if it's a link).

Comment: @luka That makes _all_ of the text ineligible for line breaking, not just the gap between the inline-block element and the first word. I still want line breaks to be possible, just not in that location.

Comment: @duskwuff -- it looks like the first character doesn't need to be in the <nobr>.  That is, using "<nobr><span class="inlineblock"></span></nobr>wide..." works just as well.  I was testing on Firefox, so you may need to check if it's okay on other browsers.

Comment: @K.A.Buhr Wow. I'll be damned. Post that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: `word-wrap: break-word;` might be what you are looking for.

Comment: @connexo That's useful in general, but doesn't help here. The line break point between the inline-block element and the text gets "used" before `break-word` comes into effect.

Comment: Note that the `nobr` tag is non-standard and it's highly discouraged to use it on production websites!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like the first character doesn't need to be in the `<nobr>` element, so this will work:

```
<nobr><span class="inlineblock"></span></nobr>wide...
```

Still ugly, but definitely less ugly!  It works on Firefox and Chrome at least.

Comment: Thanks! Oddly, applying `white-space: nowrap` directly to the inline-block span doesn't work; it has to be on a separate containing element.